# Sending "enter" key stroke on SabreCommandLLSRQ

Tags: web-services, sabre

I'm trying to use SabreCommand web service to navigate a functionality that requires to send "enter" key strokes (like the one you login with "SI").

Any idea how to do that?

I've tried sending empty requests, null request... Nothing seems to work!

Comment: You are using this webservice fro Flight Booking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say: like the one you login with "SI", maybe you are trying to navigate through a mask. There is a way of doing mask handling, which is actually not supported by the helpdesk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand correctly what you are trying to do, but SabreCommand automatically executes any command you send with it, so there's no need to simulate pressing 'enter'.
AFAIK you cannot log in using SabreCommand, but i.e. to display a PNR you simply send *LOCATOR, there's no need to send 'enter' command afterwards.